# The json encode did not return response after calling the function of fb post to wall

Tags: php, jquery, json, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I have a link which posted data to another page `vote.php` through jquery.

When I click on that link, it return the state according to the condition.
If that user posted the vote before then it displayed the "already voted" other wise "Your vote posted".

All was working fine.

I am using the facebook post to wall sdk.

Now when I call the `fb_publish_on_wall` function from the vote.php, the message successfully posted to my fb wall but it did not return the state of the vote like "Your vote posted".

What is the problem. When I comment out that line where I am calling the `fb_publish_on_wall` function then It works fine.

I think the jquery did not get response from `vote.php` after calling the `fb_publish_on_wall` function.

How will I fix this?

UPDATED: Here is the fb_publish_on_wall function

```
function fb_publish_on_wall($message,$link,$picture,$name,$description,$user_facebook2)
{
    $message = str_replace(array('<br />', '<br>'), "\n", $message);
        $description = str_replace(array('<br />', '<br>'), "\n", $description);
        $name = str_replace(array('<br />', '<br>'),"\n", $name);
        $link = str_replace(array('<br />', '<br>'), "\n", $link);

        global $facebook;

                $publishStream = $facebook->api("/$user_facebook2/feed", 'post', array(
                    'message' => "$message", 
                    'link'    => "$link",
                    'picture' => "$picture",
                    'name'    => "$name",
                    'description'=> "$description"
                    ));

        print $user_facebook2;



}
```

UPDATED: vote.php. This file is big. SO I am only displaying the that two lines from vote.php

```
echo json_encode(array("state"=>"<span style='color:#8DA326'>".l("Your vote posted").".</span>"));

    fb_publish_on_wall($message,$link,$picture,$name,$description,$user_facebook2);
```

Comment: Can you show fb_post_to_wall() function? Maybe problem with headers?

Comment: Can you post firebug/some_other_tool network dump when you make ajax request?

Comment: In firebug the Response shwoing the `Your vote posted`.

Comment: I think changing the order of statements will work. Why don't you try this: fb_publish_on_wall($message,$link,$picture,$name,$description,$user_facebook2);
echo json_encode(array("state"=>"<span style='color:#8DA326'>".l("Your vote posted").".</span>"));

Comment: Also remove the print statement, else that will also get returned to your jquery: print $user_facebook2; 
Any reason why you have that? You can handle the display if needed on our javascript by passing it along with the json encoded value

Comment: If ninja solution don't work, try set json header.

Comment: Thanks all of you. I removed the the `print $user_facebook2` from the `fb_publish_on_wall()` function and it solved my problem.

Comment: Ahmad, I have posted my comment as an answer- kindly accept it as the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the print statement in fb_publish_on_wall function, as that will also be part of the return value and will interfere with the json_encoded return value you parse in jquery.